# Which SQL Server edition to choose

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

Currently we are using SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Edition. The size of the database is less than one GB and it's not heavily used. We want to upgrade it to SQL Server 2008. Which Edition (Standard/Enterprise) would be suitable for this upgrade? The OS we'll use is Windows Server 2008.

Please advise.

Thanks,

Imran

Comment: it depends on your needs , check this out http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider the Express Edition. It has a 4GB limit (I think) and is free. If you database is not heavily used, this might work for you.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 **R2** Express has upped that limit to 10 GB

Comment: Note that SQL Server Express allocates only 1GB RAM

Answer (score 3):

Any edition will be suitable from Express up to Enterprise for this.

The question is what features do you require from Enterprise that are not available in Express.

For example, what level of High Availability do you need?

Comment: Any thoughts about when to use Work group Edition?

Comment: @Imran: not really. it's based on features + licensing costs (my own + target site)